# Why CPU speed is different from Model name

Tags: central-processing-unit

Just acquire new dedicated server under debian 8 and check some information about cpu:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1600.257
BogoMIPS:              6784.70
Virtualization:        VT-x
```

`Model name` indicate `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2130 CPU @ 3.40GHz` and `CPU MHz` indicate `1600.257`. Why displayed cpu speed are different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUs can lower their clock speed when not under load to reduce power consumption. See [Dynamic Frequency Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).

This can be configured or disabled altogether through your operating system ([e.g.](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling)).